# $K-$ algebras of finite type

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, tensor-products

Question: If $A$ and $B$ are associative algebra over
field $K$ and
$$A \otimes_K K_s \cong B \otimes_K K_s$$
as $K_s-$ algebras,
where $K_s$ is the seperable closure of $K$, and $A$
is of finite type, then so is $B$.

My attempt: Since $A$ is of finite type, then $A$ can
be generated by some
$$
a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in A \; .
$$
Then $A \otimes K_s$ is generated by
$$
a_1 \otimes 1, a_2 \otimes 1, ..., a_n \otimes 1 \; .
$$
Since we have a $K_s-$ algebra isomorphism
$$
f: A \otimes_K K_s \longrightarrow B \otimes_K K_s \; ,
$$
then $B \otimes K_s$ is generated by
$$
f(a_1 \otimes 1), f(a_2 \otimes 1), ..., 
f(a_n \otimes 1) \; .
$$
Write
$$
f(a_i \otimes 1) = \sum_{j=1}^{r_i} b_{ij} 
\otimes k_{ij} \; ,
$$
for some $b_{ij} \in B, k_{ij} \in K_s, r_i 
\in \mathbb{N}$.
I want to show $B$ is generated by
$$
b_{ij}, 1 \leq j \leq r_i, 1 \leq i \leq n \; ,
$$
but have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the $K$-algebra homomorphism $K[x_{ij}]_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq r_i}}\to B$ defined by mapping $x_{ij}\mapsto b_{ij}$. This is in particular a map of $K$-vector spaces, so let $V$ be the $K$-vector space which is the cokernel of this map. We then have an exact sequence
$$
K[x_{ij}]\to B\to V\to 0.
$$
As field extensions are flat, we obtain an exact sequence
$$
K_s[x_{ij}]\to B\otimes_K K_s\to V\otimes_K K_s\to 0.
$$
The map $K_s[x_{ij}]\to B\otimes_K K_s$ is a morphism of $K_s$ algebras and maps $k_{ij}x_{ij}$ to $b_{ij}\otimes k_{ij}$ which generate $B\otimes_K K_s$ as a $K_s$-algebra. Hence $K_s[x_{ij}]\to B\otimes_K K_s$ is surjective. Therefore $V\otimes_K K_s=0$. This implies $V=0$, so $K[x_{ij}]\to B$ was surjective to begin with.

Note that the same proof works for any field extension $L\supseteq K$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that any field extension is flat, I will learn something about it.